# Массив имен c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть массив `char *Names[] = { "Alexandr", "Kostya", "Roman" };`, пытаюсь сделать функцию случайного выбора имени и записать его в другой массив

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *Empty[100];
    char *Names[] = { "Alexandr", "Kostya", "Roman" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Empty[i] = Names[rand() % 3 + 1];
        cout << Empty[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Но выдает ошибку. Подскажите, как правильно задать? Благодарю!

Comment: ошибку предлагаете угадать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что `rand()%3+1` дает значения от 1 до 3, а элементы массивов начинают считаться с 0, так что `Names[3]` у вас просто не существует.

Все остальное сработает... но нет у меня уверенности в том, что этот код делает именно то, что вы хотите. Хотя он вполне работоспособен - если убрать `+1`.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще один вопрос, как мне избавиться от повторений имен?

Answer (score 1):

Что бы каждый раз случайное значение было разное можно применить  `srand(time(NULL));`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void) 
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  char *Empty[100];
    char *Names[] = { "Alexandr", "Kostya", "Roman" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {

        Empty[i] = Names[rand()%3];
        printf("%s\n", Empty[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще один вопрос, как мне избавиться от повторений имен?

Comment: @AlexandrT На этот вопрос я ответил в соответствующем месте :)